# Why is Swift giving me inaccurate floating point arithmetic results?

Tags: swift

Swift floating point arithmetic seems broken compared to C (and therefore Objective-C).

Let's take a simple example.
In C:

```
double output = 90/100.0; // Gives 0.9
float output = 90/100.0f; // Gives 0.9
```

In Swift:

```
var output = Double(90)/Double(100.0) // Gives 0.90000000000000002
var output = Float(90)/Float(100.0) // Gives 0.899999976
```

What's going on? Is this a bug or am I missing something?

EDIT:

```
#import <iostream>

int main() {
    double inter = 90/100.0;
    std::cout << inter << std::endl; // Outputs 0.9
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: oh anther floating arithmetic question... btw `double output = 90/100.0; // doesn't gives 0.9`

Comment: Printing the results in C with the same number of decimals would probably produce the same output.

Comment: You're missing something.  Lots of Qs&As here on SO about this, try starting at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: in fact, `double output = 0.9; // doesn't give 0.9`

Comment: #import <iostream>

int main() {
double inter = 90/100.0;
std::cout << inter << std::endl; // Output 0.9
return 0;
}

Comment: is there a swift solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is simply the different number of digits being printed out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    double d = 90.0 / 100.0;
    float f = 90.0f / 100.0f;
    std::cout << d  << ' ' << f << '\n';
    std::cout << std::setprecision(20) << d << ' ' << f << '\n';
}

0.9 0.9
0.9000000000000000222 0.89999997615814208984
```

(I wrote this example in C++, but you will get the same results in every language that uses the hardware's floating point arithmetic and allows this formatting.)

If you want to understand why finite precision floating point math does not give you exact results then:

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

And:

[Float](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/float.html)