# Swift – String with comma-separator to double

Tags: string, swift2, double, nsnumberformatter

I have currently a string like this: `"8,0"` or `"4,25"` and I need to convert it to a `Double`, but how would I do that?
Do I first replace the `,` with a `.`?

I have looked at `NSNumberFormatter` but that returned `nil` for every string.

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
let grade = formatter.numberFromString(grade["Cijfer"].stringValue)
print(grade)
```

What should I use?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `decimalSeparator`:

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.decimalSeparator = ","
let grade = formatter.numberFromString("2,3")

if let doubleGrade = grade?.doubleValue {
    print(doubleGrade)
} else {
    print("not parseable")
}
```

Prints

> 2.3

Comment: And then I can cast the NSNumber to a Double?

Comment: @jbehrens94 I included a further code snipper to explain that.

Comment: I also get returns like `9.800000000000001`?

Comment: @jbehrens94 yes, that happens, that is how floating point numbers are treated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657869/why-is-swift-giving-me-inaccurate-floating-point-arithmetic-results

Comment: Alright, is there someway I can keep it to a maximum of 2 decimal numbers?

Comment: @jbehrens94 no. 9.8 ist not exactly representable in binary. There should not arise any trouble from it. Please accept my answer since it answered your question. Dealing with floating point numbers is an entirely different topic on its own.

Answer (score 8):

'pure' Swift (no Foundation)

```
let str = "9,8"
let sstr = str.characters.split(",").joinWithSeparator(["."])
if let d = Double(String(sstr)) {
    print(d) // 9.8
}
```

Comment: or just `str.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".")`

Comment: @trickster77777 please, see what is written at the beginning. "no Foundation". Those days (2016) the Foundation framework was only partially available on a platform different from apple. Till now, this function is part of Foundation https://swiftdoc.org/v4.2/type/string/#func-replacingoccurrences-of_with_options_range_

Answer (score 1):

Robust string extension

```
extension String {
    var preparedToDecimalNumberConversion: String {
        split {
            !CharacterSet(charactersIn: "\($0)").isSubset(of: CharacterSet.decimalDigits)
        }.joined(separator: ".")
    }
}

func testPreparingToDecimalNumberConversion() {
    XCTAssertEqual("25.5".preparedToDecimalNumberConversion, "25.5")
    XCTAssertEqual("25,5".preparedToDecimalNumberConversion, "25.5")
    XCTAssertEqual("...,,,25,5,,,".preparedToDecimalNumberConversion, "25.5")
    XCTAssertEqual("25.5,42,..".preparedToDecimalNumberConversion, "25.5.42")
    XCTAssertEqual(".42,..".preparedToDecimalNumberConversion, "42")
    XCTAssertEqual(".36,,,6,..".preparedToDecimalNumberConversion, "36.6")
    XCTAssertEqual("36......6".preparedToDecimalNumberConversion, "36.6")
    XCTAssertEqual("36.,.,.,6".preparedToDecimalNumberConversion, "36.6")

    XCTAssertEqual(Float("25.5".preparedToDecimalNumberConversion), 25.5)
    XCTAssertEqual(Float("25,5".preparedToDecimalNumberConversion), 25.5)
    XCTAssertEqual(Float("...,,,25,5,,,".preparedToDecimalNumberConversion), 25.5)
    XCTAssertEqual(Float("25.5,42,..".preparedToDecimalNumberConversion), nil)
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(".42,..".preparedToDecimalNumberConversion), 42)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I encountered this error, I found a solution using this code.

`stringValue.toDouble()`